# Customising WiX FeaturesDlg - changing WiX UI in realtime

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I'd like to customise the WiX FeaturesDlg, so that if a particular server feature is selected that the user can click a button and set which user credentials are used for the service. I've put together a solution, however I note that the 'Select User' button does not enable/disable as the user changes the features - it is only re-evaluated if the user clicks back and then clicks next to return to the dialog. Is there a way so that the condition can be re-evaluated when the feature change happens?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    The use and distribution terms for this software are covered by the
    Common Public License 1.0 (http://opensource.org/licenses/cpl1.0.php)
    which can be found in the file CPL.TXT at the root of this distribution.
    By using this software in any fashion, you are agreeing to be bound by
    the terms of this license.

    You must not remove this notice, or any other, from this software.
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="NewFeaturesDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.FeaturesDlg_Title)" TrackDiskSpace="yes">
              <Control Id="Tree" Type="SelectionTree" X="20" Y="55" Width="330" Height="121" Property="_BrowseProperty" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgTree)"></Control>            
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgInstall)">
                    <Condition Action="show">NOT Installed AND ALLUSERS</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="default">NOT Installed</Condition>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="InstallNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgInstall)">
                    <Condition Action="show">NOT Installed AND NOT ALLUSERS</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="default">NOT Installed</Condition>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Change" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgChange)">
                    <Condition Action="show">Installed AND ALLUSERS AND (ADDLOCAL OR REMOVE)</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="default">Installed</Condition>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="ChangeNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgChange)">
                    <Condition Action="show">Installed AND (NOT ALLUSERS OR (NOT ADDLOCAL AND NOT REMOVE))</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="default">Installed</Condition>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgDescription)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="210" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgTitle)" />
                <Control Id="ItemDescription" Type="Text" X="20" Y="180" Width="330" Height="24" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgItemDescription)">
                    <Subscribe Event="SelectionDescription" Attribute="Text" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="ItemSize" Type="Text" X="20" Y="209" Width="330" Height="24" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.FeaturesDlgItemSize)">
                    <Subscribe Event="SelectionSize" Attribute="Text" />
                </Control>
                <Control Type="PushButton" Id="SelectUser" Width="56" Height="17" X="292" Y="188">
                    <Text>Select User</Text>
                  <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[NOT (&ServerComponents=4 OR NOT &ServerComponents=3)]]></Condition>
                  <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[ (&ServerComponents=4 OR &ServerComponents=3)]]></Condition>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain limitations (race conditions) in Windows Installer native UI such as the one you are seeing.  If you move the Select User functionality to the next dialog it will evaluate correctly.